# Отступ после переноса строки

Tags: html, css

Проблема в том чтобы перенесённая строка начиналась не под цифрами, а под началом верхней строки. Можно как-то выставить расстояние для перенесённых строк по типу 15mm?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
body {
    counter-reset: example figure issue;
    /* Layout */    
    margin: 0 auto;
    
    /* Typography */
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: Calibri light;
    font-size: 8pt;
    widows: 2;
    orphans: 2;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    text-align-last: right;
    hyphens: auto;

    /* Colors */
    color: black;   
}
```

Comment: а сам отступ вы как делаете? вы бы часть html кода еще привели

Comment: Отступ делаю: text-align-last: right;
но что-то не работает

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте пойти от обратного -

1. выставить блоку с текстом отступ слева какой вам надо через `padding`
2. скомпенсировать отступ первой строки через `text-indent`

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    
    text-align: justify;
    
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 25px;
    text-indent: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
Мой дядя самых честных правил, Когда не в шутку занемог, Он уважать себя заставил И лучше выдумать не мог. Его пример другим наука; Но, боже мой, какая скука С больным сидеть и день и ночь, Не отходя ни шагу прочь!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul{
width:200px;
background: gray;
margin-left: 100px;
box-shadow: -100px 0 0 pink;
/* чтоб видеть margin без инспектора */

list-style: none;
counter-reset: f s t q;
}
li{position: relative;}
/*для li:before{left}*/

.f > li:before{
counter-increment: f;
content: counter(f);
left: -30px;
position: absolute;
/*теперь он не будет отжирать место у первой строки*/
}
```

```html
<ul class='f'>
<li>aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa</li>
<li>bbbb bbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbb bb bbbbbbb bbbbbb</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>d</li>
<li>e</li>
<li>f</li>
</ul>
```